# Problem with browsersync proxy since I changed the apache to brew apache

Tags: apache, server, browser-sync

I've had a mackbook M2 for a few months now and from the beginning I installed Apache from BREW. Thean loaded the websites I had already created on it.

Through Grunt I load browsersync and everything was fine until a few weeks ago when the apache server that is installed by default on Mac blocked the Brew Apache.

Since then every time I start the Mac I have to close the Mac apache and start the homebrew.mxcl.httpd apache, there is no way to disable the default apache.

Now I've noticed that with this configuration the browsersync doesn't work, it doesn't proxy even if the URLS are working correctly and I'm using the same ports as with the initial configuration. Any ideas?

I tried to load special http module in browsersync without success. Also tried to change ports in BrowserSync and remove from config to let browserSync set one automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic and first rule resolution: restart the computer, all works again.